# Mysql - Single Query for One-To-Many

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have a table named `posts` and another table named `attachments`...

A `post` can have many `attachments`...

So, I create a middle table called `post_attachment`..

How to get the list of `posts` data including the `attachments` data in **A SINGLE QUERY**?

..

Please refer below to make it clearer to understand...

---

**Below are the table structure:**

-

`posts` table have 4 columns:

1. id
2. title
3. body_text

-

`attachments` table have 3 columns:

1. id
2. filename
3. file_url

-

`post_attachment` table have 2 columns:

1. post_id
2. file_id

---

**Below are the example of a `post` that have multiple `attachments`**

`posts` table:

[image]

-

`attachments` table:

[image]

-

`post_-attachment` table:

[image]

In the example above, it tells the `post` (ID: 1) has 3 `attachments` which is ID: 1,2 and 3.

So, the question is How to GET the list of posts which will have columns `posts.title`, `attachments.filename`, `attachments.file_url` in **A SINGLE QUERY**?

Answer (score 0):

You must join the 3 tables:

```
select
  p.*, a.*
from post p
left join post_attachment pa on pa.post_id = p.id
left join attachments a on a.id = pa.file_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is needed in case a post does not have any attachments.